# How to get fileopenmode in fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

For example, I used std:: ios:: in to construct a fstream. Can I get the file mode of the fstream later;
I use flags () to get flags and use "&" to get them, but I can't get them. I can't find a clear answer in the search process.

Comment: The `flags()` member function is for formatting flags only, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags . Not sure if there is a way of determining this kind of info btw: `std::basic_fstream` doesn't seem to provide this kind of info directly and I don't see this kind of info being provided by `std::basic_filebuf` either. Any reason you don't keep track of this kind of info yourself? Usually I'd either pass the fstream on as `std::ostream` or `std::istream` or create a wrapper class; in both cases the open mode should be known...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to access the open mode through the class. You can manually store the open mode to get it later though:

```
static int mode_alloc = std::ios_base::xalloc();
auto mode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out;
std::fstream stream;
stream.iword(mode_alloc) = mode;
// ...
stream.iword(mode_alloc); // the value of mode
```